# How can I get drag and drop to work for a dynamically generated table by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop, tablednd

So I am using the TableDnD plugin for drag and drop. The rows do drag and drop just fine, however when I want to get drag and drop rows of a table dynamically generated by AJAX, the code doesn't seem to work. Can anyone explain how I can make this work for a dynamically generated table as well ?

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      // Drag and drop
      $("#table-1").tableDnD({
          onDragClass: "myDragClass",
          onDrop: function (table, row) {
              var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;
              for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                  debugStr += rows[i].id + " ";
                  alert(rows[i].id);
              }
          },
          onDragStart: function (table, row) {}
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be caused because you apply **.tableDnD()** **after DOM** has been **loaded**. If you add your elements dynamically after DOM load, it won't apply to those elements.

You could detect change in DOM and apply .tableDnD() then:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(){

    $("#table-1").tableDnD({
        onDragClass: "myDragClass",
        onDrop: function (table, row) {
            var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                debugStr += rows[i].id + " ";
                alert(rows[i].id);
            }
        },
        onDragStart: function (table, row) {}
    });

});
```

Or even better:

```
$(document).ready({

    applyDnD();
    $(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', applyDnD);

    function applyDnD() {
        $("#table-1").tableDnD({
            onDragClass: "myDragClass",
            onDrop: function (table, row) {
                var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    debugStr += rows[i].id + " ";
                    alert(rows[i].id);
                }
            },
            onDragStart: function (table, row) {}
        });
    };

});
```